# Load PostGIS or Oracle Spatial Raster Layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, pyqgis, oracle-spatial

How do we load Rasters stored in PostgreSQL-PostGIS or Oracle Spatial 11g into QGIS using PyQGIS?

I am able to load vector layers from Oracle 11g with below code. What changes are necessary to add Raster layers? The files are in tif format.

```
#Connect to Oracle and Fetch Table Names 
con = cx_Oracle.connect('myoradb/myoradb@189.53.61.140:1521/newdev')
print con.version
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(u"select TABLE_NAME from user_tab_columns where data_type='SDO_GEOMETRY'")

tables = cur.fetchall()


uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("189.53.61.140", "1521", "newdev", "myoradb", "myoradb")


QgsProject.instance().writeEntry('WFSLayers', "/", [])


for t in tables :
   print str(t[0])

   uri.setDataSource('',  str(t[0]), "GEOMETRY")
   uri.uri()
   vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),str(t[0]), 'oracle')
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
   lst = [ vlayer.id() ]
   pWfsLayer.append(u'%s' % vlayer.id())
   pLayers.append(u'%s' % vlayer.name())
   pLayerIDs.append(vlayer.id())

   render.setLayerSet(lst)
   rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())            
   rect.scale(1.1)
   render.setExtent(rect)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your raster is stored in PostGIS, you can load it using PyQGIS (e.g., from the QGIS Python console) this way:

```
connString = "PG: dbname=myDBname host=localhost user=myUser password=myPassword port=5432 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=myRasterTable" 
layer = QgsRasterLayer( connString, "My PostGIS Raster" )

if layer.isValid():
    layer.setContrastEnhancement( QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum )

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer( layer )
```

You would need to adjust all parameters in the connection string that start with "my," like "myDBname."

Additionally, as you may have noticed, I'm passing a `column` parameter with value `rast`. The value of the parameter column is taken from the view `raster_columns` in your database, namely, from the field `r_raster_column` as you see in the picture below:

[image]

If necessary, you could of course get such value by executing a SQL query before setting your connection string. Something like:

```
SELECT r_raster_column FROM raster_columns \
    WHERE r_table_schema = 'public' AND \
    r_table_name = 'myRasterTable'
```

Comment: @gccarillo...Brilliant, it is working with PostGIS when I used raster2pgsql to load raster files.Thanks much.I hope this works for 11g too.

Comment: @Durga Great! Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it was useful to you. That's how you reward answerers in GIS.StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very important part of how GIS.SE works. You could also take the [GIS.SE tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), which explains other aspects of GIS.SE.

Comment: @gccarillo ,what is the connection string for Oracle Spatial..In place of PG in the above connection string,what is the keyword for Oracle Spatial?

Comment: @Durga I've never worked with Oracle Spatial, sorry.